# Determining if propositions with quantifiers are the same

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

if you are given 2 propositions with quantifiers, what is the method to find out that they are equivalent? For example the three propositions:

$\exists c : \exists n_0 : \forall n : n \geq n_0 \rightarrow f(n) \geq cg(n)$

$\forall n_0 : \exists c : \forall n : n \geq n_0 \rightarrow f(n) \geq cg(n)$

$\forall c : \exists n_0 : \forall n : n \geq n_0 \rightarrow f(n) \geq cg(n)$

How would we determine any of these propositions are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the different quantifiers, most likely these three statements are all different.  To demonstrate that, come up with a domain and interpretation for the functions so that the statements get different truth-values.

OK, for our domain, let's use the natural numbers

For the functions, let's first pick $f(n)=g(n)=n$

Then the three statements become:

$\exists c : \exists n_0 : \forall n : n \geq n_0 \rightarrow n \geq cn$

$\forall n_0 : \exists c : \forall n : n \geq n_0 \rightarrow n \geq cn$

$\forall c : \exists n_0 : \forall n : n \geq n_0 \rightarrow n \geq cn$

Now, the first two statements are true, since for $c$ we can just pick $c=0$, and it will always be true that $n \geq 0$

The third statement, however, is not true, because for $c=2$ then, no matter what you pick for $n_0$, the conditional will evaluate to false for $n=n_0+1$, since then $n\geq n_0$, but not $n \geq cn$

OK, so now we know the third statement is not equivalent to either the first or the second statement.

Now, can you think of a choice for $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ that differentiate between the first two statements?

Comment: what do you mean by the fact that $c$ is not used in the formula? Isn't it used as the coefficient of $g$ ?

Comment: @LukeYeh Oh!  I was looking at that as a function $cg(x)$.... ok, if that is meant as $c \cdot g(x)$, then everything changes! Now the question becomes: are you looking for *logical* equivalence, where $f$ and $g$ can be any function youm want, or are $f$ and $g$ *given*, in which case we could be talking about *mathematical* equivalence? For example, maybe $g(x)$ is given as $g(x)=0$?

Comment: I believe that I am looking for logical equivalence. $f$ and $g$ could be any arbitrary function.

Comment: @LukeYeh OK, sounds god.  I just changed my answer and show how you can demonstrate non-equivalence. I showed that the third statement is not equivalent to either of the first two.  See if you can use a similar method to demonstrate that the first two statements are not equivalent. Let me know if you're still struggling.